# iOS - ALAssetsGroupPropertyName returns null album name

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary

I am trying to retrieve all photo album names and all photos with that album name. The album names I got from `[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName]` are mostly correct but there was one album name that says `(null)` and the album called `Favorites` does not show.

Album names array:

```
((null), Camera Roll, Last Import, Nissan Juke, Cam)
```

Here's my code

```
-(void)getPhotosFromAssetsLibWithPhotoFilter:(NSString *)filterAlbumString
{
    _assets = [@[] mutableCopy];
    __block NSMutableArray *tmpAssets = [@[] mutableCopy];
    __block NSMutableArray *albumGroup = [@[] mutableCopy];
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [PhotoLibViewController defaultAssetsLibrary];
    [assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
    {
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
        {
            if(result)
            {
                if (![filterAlbumString isEqualToString:@""])
                {
                    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName]] isEqualToString:filterAlbumString])
                    {
                        [tmpAssets addObject:result];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    [tmpAssets addObject:result];
                }
            }
        }];

        [albumGroup addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName]]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(retrievedPhotoLibrary:)])
            {
                NSArray *albumGroupReversed = [[albumGroup reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
                [self retrievedPhotoLibrary:albumGroupReversed];
            }
        });

        self.assets = [[tmpAssets reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];

        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error loading images %@", error);
    }];
}
```

I would like to know why there is a `(null)` album name and why the album name `Favorites` does not show.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the enumeration is done, `enumerationBlock` is invoked with group set to nil, so you should check each time the `group` is nil or not and execute `reloadData` only on the enumeration is done. The proper logic  should look like this:

```
[assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
{
    if (group != nil) 
    {
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
        {
            if(result)
            {
                if (![filterAlbumString isEqualToString:@""])
                {
                    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName]] isEqualToString:filterAlbumString])
                    {
                        [tmpAssets addObject:result];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    [tmpAssets addObject:result];
                }
            }
        }];

        [albumGroup addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName]]];        
    }  
    else 
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(retrievedPhotoLibrary:)])
            {
                NSArray *albumGroupReversed = [[albumGroup reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
                [self retrievedPhotoLibrary:albumGroupReversed];
            }
        });

        self.assets = [[tmpAssets reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];

        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error loading images %@", error);
}];
```

For the `Favorites`, it's a new feature in `PhotoKit` for iOS8:

> With iOS 8, Apple has given us PhotoKit, a modern framework that’s more performant than AssetsLibrary and provides features that allow applications to work seamlessly with a device’s photo library.
>
> **Favorite and Hidden Assets**
>
> To find out if an asset was marked as favorite or was hidden by the user, just inspect the favorite and hidden properties of the PHAsset instance.
>
> See also: [The Photos Framework](http://www.objc.io/issues/21-camera-and-photos/the-photos-framework/)

So you have to show the `Favorites` via the `PhotoKit` framework, check the official sample project: [ExampleappusingPhotosframework.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gudhgdsznai3xoq/ExampleappusingPhotosframework.zip?dl=0).

Comment: I'll add that iCloud Shared Albums may have name issues.